# Calculating SUM of multiple fields into new field using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, cursor

I have 4 fields (STREAMS, SLOPE_ASPECT, FIRES, TREES) that are assigned either a 1 or a 0 based on whether they exist or not.

The goal: Create a new field "ranking" the best locations (essentially, where all four = 1)

The assignment says "Create a RANK field and calculate the sum of the 4 fields".
I am currently trying to use a SearchCursor and InsertCursor from another question about something similar but this results in no change and continues displaying "NULL". I am very new to this.

Here's what I've got:

```
SearchArea = r'C:...'
fc = SearchArea
#Establish local variable for Ranks field
MushroomRanks = "RANKS"
newFields = ['STREAMS', 'SLOPE_ASPECT', 'FIRES', 'TREES', 'RANKS']
#Add RANKS field
arcpy.AddField_management(SearchArea, MushroomRanks, "SHORT")
#Create a variable for our SUM
values = []
#Search cursor to calculate the sum of new fields and store them into a "values" variable
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, newFields) as Scursor:
    thisValue = 0
    for row in Scursor:
    thisValue += row[0]
    values.append(thisValue)
newFields.append(MushroomRanks)
#Inserts the stored sums
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc, MushroomRanks) as cur:
      cur.insertRow(values)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code appears to attempt to copy all the `"STREAMS"` values (`row[0]`) to the `"RANKS"` field and ignores all the other fields (`row[1:4]`).

But then you use an `InsertCursor` instead of an `UpdateCursor` and attempt to append those `"STREAM"` values as new rows instead of updating the `"RANK"` field in the existing rows.

You could do this with a simple [Calculate Fields](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-field.htm) expression without any scripting at all, e.g.

```
sum([!STREAMS!, !SLOPE_ASPECT!, !FIRES!, !TREES!])
```

Or if if you want to use arcpy:

```
arcpy.management.CalculateField(
    fc, MushroomRanks, 
    "sum([!STREAMS!, !SLOPE_ASPECT!, !FIRES!, !TREES!])", 
    "PYTHON3")
```

But if you must use a cursor, use an [`UpdateCursor`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) not an `InsertCursor` and there's no need for a `SearchCursor` at all:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, newFields) as rows:
    for row in rows:
        row[-1] = sum(row[:-1])  # sum all values except the last and assign to the last (row[-1])
        # Does the same as
        # row[4] = sum(row[0:4]) # sum 1st 4 values and assign to the 5th (row[-1])
        rows.updateRow(row)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! I wasn't able to get the UpdateCursor to work, it returned:

"line 94, in <module>
    rows.updateRow(row)
StopIteration: iteration not started"

However, the CalculateField is all I needed for this one, I had to play around with cursors before reaching this point so I think I was just overthinking it.

Thank you for the notes and help with the syntax of the rows in the Update cursor, that will come in handy. I greatly appreciate your help and guidance!

Comment: For some reason, I lost an indentation level when I pasted the UpdateCursor code. Should be fixed now. I noticed, but neglected to refer to it, that your indentation is incorrect in the line after  `    for row in Scursor:`. Don't forget python uses indentation as part of the language syntax.